# Snowflake: Options for viewing column details in Preview App

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There are currently 4 details available in the Preview App when I explore a Table, and click on "Columns" tab.
They are:
NAME
TYPE
NULLABLE
DEFAULT

[Screenshot of User Interface with column details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFDGW.png)

Is it possible for users or administrators to customize which column details are visible here? If not, are there plans to make this customizable?

I want to show the "Comment" detail in this view, and hide the Default detail since it is irrelevant for my users.

Comment: As of now I don't see an option to customize that list, not even as accountadmin. Not sure if there are plans to change it, but I can suggest to create an Idea for it on our [**Idea**](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Search-Create-Vote-Follow-Ideas) portal.

Answer (score 0):

use the following query instead of the new preview app:

describe table mytable;

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-table.html